# react.js - ReactCSSTransitionGroup throws exception

Tags: javascript, animation, css-transitions, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to add animations for enter into my list inside React.js app (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).

But `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` throws such exceptions:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_mockedReactClassConstructor' of undefined`

together with warnings:

`Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
warning.js:36`

`Warning: Only functions or strings can be mounted as React components.`

My component looks like:

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var items = this.props.data
        .filter(function (item) {
            return item.stream;
        })
        .map(function (item) {
            return <div key={item.id}>item.name</div>;
        });

      return (
        <div className="list clearfix">
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
                {items}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
     );
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide more data? Can you create a test-case on jsfiddle?

Comment: this one - http://jsfiddle.net/r98d348f/3/ works fine until you'll wrap `{items}` into `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the original answer was based on the assumption that the above code was correct, here the revised one, based on your fiddle.

In your fiddle you do not propery reference the ReactCSSTransitionGroup. You reference it as `React.ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, which of course is `undefined`. This is why your fiddle will complain, if you try to wrap anything in it, because you are using an undefined value. To get your fiddle working, you will have to reference the css transition group like this:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
```

The corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r98d348f/4/

Comment: Ok, fiddle works but added CSS transitions didn't apply - updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r98d348f/5/

Comment: Also I managed to fix exceptions in my real code with `React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;` but animation is still not present.

Comment: Yes it present, as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/r98d348f/7/ What you want though is an animation on 'appear', not 'enter'. This has only recently been implemented and is not yet available in an official release. (https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/8760a70e735cd7afcf70108c133d7df81fda3ef3), Latest release: http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.2.js - notice that the 'appear' transitions are missing. You could get around the issue by rendering once without data and then immediatly rendering again, with your initial data.

Comment: Regarding rerendering, `forceUpdate` in `componentDidMount` didn't work for that - http://jsfiddle.net/r98d348f/8/

Comment: I feel like this is a documentation issue.  I've had the same issue in the past because the docs all reference `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` rather than `CSSTransitionGroup`.  The same is true for `ReactTransitionGroup` and `TransitionGroup`.

Comment: @Kosmetika I was not referring to using `forceUpdate`, but rather another call to `React.render`, after you are sure that you have your data available. Because you will have to render your component initially empty (until the appear-hook arrives) and then again with data in order to get the animation you want.